# What's the cleanest or most idiomatic way to remove all of a user's roles for a particular resource?

Tags: ruby, rolify

I can do this. Is there a more idiomatic way or something directly supported by the API?

```
transaction do
  Organization.find_roles(:any, organization).where(resource_id: organization.id).pluck(:name).each |role_name|
    remove_role(role_name, organization)
  end
  add_role('new_role', organization)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of all of those roles then this should do it: (basically what `remove_role` does but without additional filters or callbacks)

```
roles
  .where(
    resource_type: 'Organization', 
    resource_id: organization.id)
  .delete_all
```

If you want it to act more like `remove_role` then this might be a better way to go:

```
self.class.adapter.remove(
  self,
  Organization
    .find_roles(:any, organization),
  organization)
```

[`Rolify::Adapter::RoleAdapter`](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/blob/master/lib/rolify/adapters/active_record/role_adapter.rb#L58)